# Pass paths of directory contents as arguments to batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have a batch file ("drag_target.bat") onto which I drag multiple files. Windows then passes the dragged file paths as arguments:

```
drag_target.bat "dragged file 1 path" "dragged file 2 path" ...
```

A common task I have to perform is to drag all the contents of a particular folder (call it "c:\foo\bar") onto drag_target.bat.

I would like to automate this task by wrapping the first batch file in another batch file ("double_clickable.bat"). But how can I list all the contents of a particular folder as arguments?

So, for example, if "c:\foo\bar" contained the following:

> a.txt
>
> b.avi
>
> c [is a sub-folder]

then I would want double_clickable.bat to invoke the following:

```
drag_target.bat "c:\foo\bar\a.txt" "c:\foo\bar\b.avi" "c:\foo\bar\c"
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `double_clickable.bat` file should do that:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "args="
set "folder=%1"
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b "%1"') do set args=!args! "%folder%\%%G"
drag_target.bat !args!
```

To use, drag any folder to this batch file.